# Can I use "data-target" to call another template?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
data-target="<?php get_template_part('template/sidenav')?>"
```

I am trying to toggle collapsed header to show the collapsed nav items in form of a dropdown menu. To do so I put the collapsed header in a new php template. Can I use data-target to call this php template on click of the icon?

Comment: Why can't you hide/show a block? PHP is rendered before the HTML, so quite confused as to how you plan to apply this?

Comment: Depending on your CSS. You can target it `[data-target="mytemplate"]` and all its childs will be part of `mytemplate`

Comment: The reason I want to render a new template is to make my html/css cleaner as the new dropdown of the collapsed header is completely different design that the original template.